# Send IncomingMessage and ServerResponse to child process

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to write a multithreaded application and I need to send an http.IncomingMessage and an http.ServerResponse objects to a child process created using child_process.fork(). Is there a way to do so?

**EDIT**

More info about what I would like to do: I'm writing a server application which would manage 'vhosts'. Each vhost has its own worker process, when the server app receives an HTTP request, it transfers it to the corresponding vhost process. But I can't find any way to transfer the underlying http.IncomingMessage and http.ServerResponse objects.

Comment: Have a look at [clustering](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) which suggests that you should have your child forks manage *their own* http instances

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I added some details about what I'm trying to achieve, your solution is interesting but is it possible that every child listening on the same port receives all the requests (each child must test is it should handle the request)?